# Can you take a look at my document.write in my array

Tags: javascript, arrays, document.write

I've been chewing on this array issue for some time now, I'm hoping the community can help me out with this one.

Here is my array setup now in my .js file:

```
let pokemon=
    [{name: 'Espeon', height: '2\'11"', type: 'Psychic',},
    {name: 'Umbreon', height: '3\' 03"', type: ['Dark', 'normal']}
    ];
    for (let i = 0; i < pokemon.length;
    i++) {
      document.write("Pokemon: " + pokemon[i].name + " | " 
      + " Height: " + pokemon[i].height + "<br />");
    }
```

console.log(text);

It works in https://replit.com/ ( https://replit.com/@LaurenPortee/HilariousCylindricalSmalltalk#script.js ) but not on my actual webpage. I'm not sure where i'm going wrong here.

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? What did you try to resolve the problem?

Comment: Hey, Nico! Thanks for the reply. The document.write doesn't seem to work on my webpage. I'm not sure why it wouldn't show.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it